# Cannot click tag <a> with <i class> selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I want to make a simple attendance automation with python for my college, I make this for ease, because this took so many button to click but, I cannot click the tag `<a>` with tag `<i>` inside it.

```
<a href="http://siakad.polinema.ac.id/mahasiswa/tr_absensi/add" 
class="btn btn-sm green-meadow btn-add-data" id="btn-add-wizard">
<i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Absen</a>
```

I use this `wait` function, and still not directed into that link. It shows nothing on result. `Process finished with exit code 0`

```
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[contains(@href, ""'http://siakad.polinema.ac.id/mahasiswa/tr_absensi/add')]"))).click()
```

I tried using `ID` and `LINK_TEXT` and still showing `Process finished with exit code 0`.

Thank you, apologize for my english. Enghlish is not my main language. If you need more information about my question, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click on the element with text as **Absen** you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following *Locator Strategies*:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.btn.btn-sm.green-meadow.btn-add-data#btn-add-wizard[href$='id/mahasiswa/tr_absensi/add']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='btn btn-sm green-meadow btn-add-data' and @id='btn-add-wizard'][contains(@href, 'id/mahasiswa/tr_absensi/add')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```